# Sharing a network share across networks?

Tags: windows, networking, samba

I have a network share (samba) running on my home network. I have a domain name that updates with my dynamic IP so I always know where my network is.

How can I connect to my network share at work, which is on an entirely different network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the network administrator at your work if he can provide you with VPN access. A VPN connection will allow you to access resources at your work as if you were sitting right at your desk.

E.g `Start -> Run -> \\fileserver`

Comment: We already use a VPN to connect to our client's network. I was under the impression that chaining VPN's was either impossible, or a bad thing.

Comment: You can have multiple VPN connections depending on how the connection exposes the internal network. Overlap will cause issues. Are you just trying to transfer files from work to home?

Comment: I'm really just trying to stream music from home.

Comment: I would not recommend trying to expose an SMB/CIFS share to the internet, most ISPs block this at their level anyway due to the popularity of exploiting SMB/CIFS for distributing malware. A better option would be a media server such as shoutcast. You can then simply open up the ports in your home router to allow external users to connect in (you).